# Django rest api in serializer

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

Model:

```
class Timings(models.Model):
    Timings_to = models.TimeField(blank=True)
    Timings_from = models.TimeField(blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.Timings_to) + '' + str(self.Timings_from)

class Temple(models.Model):
    history = models.TextField(blank=False)
    timings = models.ManyToManyField(Timings, blank=False, related_name='temple_timing')
    establishment = models.CharField(max_length=20, choices=ESTABLISHMENT_CHOICE,
                                     blank=True, default=None
                                     )
```

My question How i can write serializer for these class. I am very new in django and rest.

Seiralizer:

```
class TimingsCreateUpdateSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    """ Timing Serializer for create """
    Timings_to = serializers.TimeField(format="%I:%M%p")
    Timings_from = serializers.TimeField(format="%I:%M%p")

    class Meta:
        model = Timings
        fields = ('id', 'Timings_to', 'Timings_from',)
        read_only = ('id',)

class TempleSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    timings = TimingsCreateUpdateSerializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Temple
        fields = '__all__'
```

I try to override create method according to documention of restfull api. but it not works, please tell me the correct way t write serializer class for this model.

```
def create(self, validated_data):
    timings_data = validated_data.pop('timings')
    temple = Temple.objects.create(**validated_data)
    for time_data in timings_data:
        Timings.objects.create(temple=temple, **time_data)
    return temple
```

temple object is created but in "Timings.objects.create(temple=temple, **time_data)" shows this error

```
>>> serializer = TempleSerializer(data=data)
>>> serializer.is_valid()
True
>>> serializer.save()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\aryan\prabhat\anakonda\envs\sarvam\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\serializers.py", line 192, in save
    self.instance = self.create(validated_data)
  File "C:\Users\aryan\prabhat\sarvam_src\institute\serializers.py", line 103, in create
    Timings.objects.create(temple=temple, **time_data)
  File "C:\Users\aryan\prabhat\anakonda\envs\sarvam\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\manager.py", line 122, in manager
_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\aryan\prabhat\anakonda\envs\sarvam\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 399, in create
    obj = self.model(**kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\aryan\prabhat\anakonda\envs\sarvam\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 451, in __init__
    raise TypeError("'%s' is an invalid keyword argument for this function" % list(kwargs)[0])
TypeError: 'temple' is an invalid keyword argument for this function
```

Answer (score 0):

You have created them, you are using `ModelSerializer` for your Django `models` instance, so from the `rest_frameworks` [docs](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#modelserializer):

> The ModelSerializer class provides a shortcut that lets you
>   automatically create a Serializer class with fields that correspond to
>   the Model fields.
>
> The ModelSerializer class is the same as a regular Serializer class,
>   except that:
>
> - It will automatically generate a set of fields for you, based on the    model.
> - It will automatically generate validators for the serializer, such as    unique_together validators
> - It includes simple default implementations of .create() and    .update().

I have tested your `serializers` and they are created, you just need not to `def create` method for them because it is implemented by default when you use `ModelSerializer` class, just go inside `./manage.py shell` and inspect them like so:

```
>>> from test_rest_create_method.serializers import TimingsCreateUpdateSerializer
>>> serializer = TimingsCreateUpdateSerializer()
>>> print(repr(serializer))
TimingsCreateUpdateSerializer():
    id = IntegerField(label='ID', read_only=True)
    Timings_to = TimeField(format='%I:%M%p')
    Timings_from = TimeField(format='%I:%M%p')
```

and the other one is

```
from test_rest_create_method.serializers import TempleSerializer
>>> serializer_temple = TempleSerializer()
>>> print(repr(serializer_temple))
TempleSerializer():
    history = CharField(style={'base_template': 'textarea.html'})
    timings = TimingsCreateUpdateSerializer(many=True):
        id = IntegerField(label='ID', read_only=True)
        Timings_to = TimeField(format='%I:%M%p')
        Timings_from = TimeField(format='%I:%M%p')
```

Comment: it show some error when i try to save my validated_data
>>serializerc.save()
Traceback (most recent call last):
   in save
    self.instance = self.create(validated_data)
   in create
    raise_errors_on_nested_writes('create', self, validated_data)
  in raise_errors_on_nested_writes
    class_name=serializer.__class__.__name__
AssertionError: The `.create()` method does not support writable nested fields by default.
Write an explicit `.create()` method for serializer `institute.serializers.TempleSerializer`, or set `read_only=True` on nested serializer fields.

Comment: did you read this part of [ModelSerializer](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#additional-keyword-arguments), you are not defining your create method properly, I've tried it and it works for me, try doing it by the book

Comment: if i use default create without override is it work?

Answer (score 0):

```
def create(self, validated_data):
    timings_data = validated_data.pop('timings')
    temple = Temple.objects.create(**validated_data)

    for time_data in timings_data:
        obj2 = Timings.objects.create(**time_data)
        temple.timings.add(obj2)
    return temple
```

This is the perfect ans Thanks to everyone..